# Test Cases for blocking visibility

Tags: testing, acceptance-testing, manual-testing

What will be the  test case for the condition:
On some criteria i.e 'resolution still not taken' ,the user with this criteria is blocked to visibility of an issue information?

Answer (score 0):

Test case can be like this:

**Steps:**

1) Open the application.

**Expected result**: Application should get opened successfully.

2) Open the issue resolution status module.

**Expected Result**: Issue resolution status module should get opened successfully.

3) Check the status of issue.

**Expected Result**:

If status of issue is 'resolution still not taken' then user with this criteria is blocked to visibility of this issue.

If status is *something else* then do *whatever your application says to do*.

Note: I just mentioned raw structure of test case. You can write this in format which you use for your test case.